# select element automatically within QTreeView based model

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I have tried the example from the Qt for Python documentation which is here:
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_widgets_itemviews_editabletreemodel.html#editable-tree-model-example

After executing the example, I added some rows and child items as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNfst.png)

Now, I am willing to select the Country automatically so that they can be highlighted one by one from the code but not by the user.
I tried as follow:

```
selection_model = self.treeView.selectionModel()
selection_model.select(arg1, arg2)
```

Now here in select)() method requires 2 arguments. could be like below:

```
select(index: QModelIndex | QPersistentModelIndex, command: SelectionFlag) -> None
select(selection: QItemSelection, command: SelectionFlag) -> None
```

My question is, how I can create the QModelIndex or QItemSelection and SelectionFlag objects to select the item from the code?

My Second question is, if I want to change the Tree data dynamically, for example want to change City from 'Toronto' to 'Hamilton', is there any api to do that without re-drawing the whole tree?

Thank you for your help. let me know is any more details required in my question.

Comment: Please note that you can only ask one question per post. I'd suggest you to start by studying the [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) documentation, then study the code you're using by looking up the documentation of each class or function it uses. Note that your first question is a bit unclear: what do you mean by "highlighted one by one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from the same example that I have linked in my question.
You can select(highlight) any item within tree by using: (To select first child within the root item)

```
# selects root    
index: QModelIndex = selection_model.currentIndex()
selection_model.setCurrentIndex(self._standard_model.index(0, 0, index), QItemSelectionModel.SelectionFlag.ClearAndSelect) 
# selects first child within root       
index: QModelIndex = selection_model.currentIndex()
selection_model.setCurrentIndex(self._standard_model.index(0, 0, index), QItemSelectionModel.SelectionFlag.ClearAndSelect)
```

And you can edit the Tree item values by code using:

```
index: QModelIndex = self.model.index(1, 1, QModelIndex()) # to edit value at (1, 1)
model: QAbstractItemModel = self.view.model()
model.setData(index, "[No data]", Qt.EditRole)
```